# Laravel Eloquent: Get record that contains two specific relations

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have a project where a user can create conversations with other users. A conversation can `belongsToMany` users and user can `belongsToMany` conversations.

I now need to get the conversation in which two specific users participate.

I tried a combination of solutions using `whereIn` and I tried the following:

```
$c = Conversation::whereHas('users', function($q)
     {
         $q->whereIn('user_id', array(1,3));
     })
    ->get();
```

Here the problem is that `whereIn('user_id', [1,3])` gets records that contains *EITHER* 1 or 3. I need it to return records that contains *BOTH* 1 and 3.

**Conversation Model**

```
class Conversation extends Model {

    public function users(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
    }
}
```

**User Model**

```
class User extends Model {

    public function conversations(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Conversation');
    }

}
```

**Tables**

**conversations:**

id | subject

**conversation_user:**

id | user_id | conversation_id

**Data from table conversation_user**

[image]

Comment: Are you sure users 1 and 3 didn't belong to every conversation you had?  What you already tried looks right to me.

Comment: yes, I included a screenshot of the current data in the table for clarity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your newest edit makes a lot more sense, this is actually a very easy fix.  `whereHas` takes two additional parameters where it's going to look for the count.

```
$users = [1, 3];   

$c = Conversation::whereHas('users', function($q) use ($users)
{
    $q->whereIn('user_id', $users);
}, '>', count($users) )
->get();
```

This will get all conversations where user's 1 and 3 have participated in, even if there are additional users that have participated in those conversations.  If you want only the conversations with only users 1 and 3, change the `>` to an `=`.

Edit: I just realized your pivot table has an `id` column.  This method may not work if your pivot table is going to have duplicates.  For example, if you have user_id of 1 in there twice with the same conversation_id both times, it will return that conversation even though it technically only has 1 user.  I suggest removing the `id` column and creating a composite primary key of `user_id` and `conversation_id`.  If there is the possibility of duplicates, it might be safer to use lukasgeiter's solution.

Answer (score 2):

You are currently querying conversations which either user 1 and/**or** 3 takes part in. To achieve what you want you need two `whereHas` calls:

```
$c = Conversation::whereHas('users', function($q)
     {
         $q->where('user_id', 1);
     })
     ->whereHas('users', function($q)
     {
         $q->where('user_id', 3);
     }
     ->get();
```

And if you have more than two users, add them in a loop:

```
$users = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
$c = Conversation::query();
foreach($users as $userId){
    $c->whereHas('users', function($q) use ($userId)
    {
        $q->where('user_id', $userId);
    });
}
$c = $c->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you...

```
    $userIds = array(1,3);
    $c = Conversation::whereHas('users', function($q) use ($userIds)
         {
             $q->whereIn('user_id', $userIds);
         })
        ->get();
```

Comment: Appreciated, don't worry I only hardcoded the id's to reduce excess code in the question and to help identify the cause of my problem. This will not solve my problem.